# SwiftUI Picker и SwiftData

Tags: ios, swift, mac, swiftui, ipad

Как используя Picker из SwiftUI сделать выбор объектов из массива выборки SwiftData?
Например такой код не работает

```
@State private var author: Author? = nil
@Query(sort: \Author.name) private var authors: [Author]
...
Picker("Автор", selection: $author) {
                    ForEach(authors) {author in
                        Text(author.name).tag(author)
                    }
                }
```